# How to compare WebdriverIO reports and generate the difference?

Tags: node.js, json, selenium, webdriver-io, mochawesome

We are using `WebdriverIO` for our automated tests and we generate HTML reports with `Mochawesome` in the end based on the result JSON files.

Now we have a lot of implemented tests and we want to fetch the difference between two testruns as fast as possible. Therefore it would be cool if we will have a possibility to compare two testrun results with each other and to generate also a HTML report only with the test result differences.

Maybe there is a still existing implemantation/package to do that? Yes, of course it is possible to compare the two different JSON result files with each other, but I prefer a still implemented solution to save effort.

How would you do the comparison in my case?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a job in a CI tool like Jenkins.

Here it always compares the latest results with the previous build and tells you if it is a new failure, regression issue or a fixed script.

1. Regression indicates that test passed in the previous build, but failing in the new build
2. Failed indicates, it is failing from the past couple of builds
3. Fixed indicates, that it was failing in the last build, but now passing in the latest build

[image: Sample Report]

Comment: what CI system you are using? and if it is Jenkins what plugin is it?

Comment: Hi Martin, I am using Jenkins . Results are using Junit Report plugin

Comment: Ah ok, so with the JUnit plugin it is possible to get such history data? That would be a possible solution. Thanks! I will give it a try 

Comment: I wish you the Best Martin!